# Network Path Name in Windows 10 1903+ (Also 2004) has wrong capitalization! How to fix?

Tags: windows-10, shared-folders

Before Windows 10 1903, whenever I want to share or map a network drive, the hostname and foldername and capitalization as what I wrote.

For instance if the hostname is `MyComputer` and the shared drive is `C` (capital) I will get the network path as `\\MyComputer\C`, but nowadays on a fresh Windows 10 install I notice I get like this `\\Mycomputer\c`, you can see the screenshot below on a fresh Windows install without anything done!

[image]

Can you please give me a registry fix or anything because it is annoying!

Or is it a Windows 10 bug?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Paths to shared folders are not case sensitive!

Comment: It is actually only a visual beautify issue, I am used to see Network Path has the same capitalization as the hostname prior to 1903

Comment: You can write them capitalized (when accessing), still not sure what the problem is?!

Comment: Every fresh Windows 10 install has a hostname of DESKTOP and random words/numberd all caps, as you can see in the uploaded picture the network path has the first letter capital only instead of everything capital.

Comment: seems it's limited to one-letter shared folders (see answer)

Comment: I think it is not limited to one letter drive only, I think you need to write mixed letters in shared drive/folder name to enforce correct capitalization, so if you write all small or all caps would make the problem appear again.

Comment: it does (see answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not a bug, it's regular system behaviour. Seems that somebody changed a line of code in one of the last updates without thinking about it too much. You can still capitalize letter if you use more the one letter (at least one lower case letter, or, with the current Win version, it will be all lower case again ), e.g. `\\hostname\C-Drive`.

By the way if you click on advanced settings the capital letter is still there. It's just not shown in the network-path of that window.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm that changing the default share name from drive letter (C) to something like (C-Drive) would fix the visual issue!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you try to call it "C-DRIVE" or something else all-caps?

Comment: @user1686 it becomes all lower case case again ;'D

Comment: Then it's most likely a function very similar to what Windows 95/98 used to have: originally the filesystem wasn't case-preserving and all file names were in all-caps, so Windows 95 would detect that and display them in "Sentence case" instead. Similarly, the default automatically generated computer name in Win7-10 has been all uppercase so far, and I suspect they applied the same filter here – but instead of applying to just the hostname, they applied it to the whole UNC thing at once.